Thriller/sci-fi movie identification
I am looking for this thriller/sci-fi movie. The main plot is that passengers and crew of an airplane travel to the world that is "behind" time in real world by flying through portal in sky. Anyone that is not sleeping disappears. This world is at first empty, food is rotten, air is bad. Then some monsters come and eat whole world, like as they clean it after it ceased to exist in normal time perspective. Some of the crew and passangers escape and end up flying through the same portal. But now they outrun the time and have to wait for it to catch with them.
It is older movie from 80' or 90'. I think that it is in english and it is straight to vhs one. One of the main character is some blind girl and really upset bussinesman that is losing his nerves. I don't remember any famous actor from it. Anyone knows what I am describing here?

The Movie you are describing is a TV Mini-Series called Langoliers (1995), an Adaption of a Stephen King book:

On a red eye flight to Boston from LA 10 people wake up to a shock. All the passengers and crew have vanished. When they try to contact the ground they make no connections. They land the plane only to discover that things haven't changed. But its like the world is dead. No one is there, the air is still, sound doesn't echo, the food is tasteless. And a distant sound is heard coming closer. A race of monstrous beings bent on their destruction is heading for them, eating everything in sight

